# OpenCL kernel parameters

Tags: kernel, opencl

I am new in OpenCL.
I want to tranfer a type int parameter in the kernel to do the operations, but I don't know how to do this. I have only worked with vectors and matrix, but I have never transfer an atribute.

If I have this code example below:

```
typedef struct{
  int fila;
  int columna;
  int value; 
}Matrix;

int main(){

  Matrix matrix;
  matrix.row = 56;
  matrix.column = 64;
  matrix.value = 0;
  float A[matrix.fila][matrix.columna];
}
```

In the kernel:

```
__kernel void matrix(__global int vue) {
     value = value + 10; //it is only an example
}
```

Can I do that operation above of "matrix.valor" (value + 10) in the kernel?? Or it is only for vectors and matrix operations? 
Do I need cl_mem or it is not necessary? I'am currently lost with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `__global` from the kernel parameter. Then, in your C/C++ code, have a variable of type `cl_int` (declared in cl.h) and set it to the value you want to pass into the kernel. Before enqueing the kernel (with `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`) call `clSetKernelArg` with parameters of your kernel, the parameter index (0), sizeof(cl_int), and the address of your variable (e.g., `clSetKernelArg(myKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_int), &myVariable)`.

[Here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html) is the documentation for clSetKernelArg. Also, search for just about any piece of OpenCL [sample code](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/art_chisnall_opencl/elementLinks/opencl.c.html).